# Combing two JSONs objects into one array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looping through and object and getting the `data-attributes`. After that I'm parsing it as a JSON:

```js
Object.entries(buyProductData).forEach(entry => {
  const [key, value] = entry;
  if(typeof value === 'object') {
    const data = JSON.parse(value.getAttribute('data-tracking-payload'));
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

`console.log(data)` returns two objects:

```js
{pid: '9783834649867', sku: '9783834649867', name: 'Book 1'}
{pid: '9683271123215', sku: '7552163721', name: 'Book 2'}
```

My question is now how can I combine the two objects so I can have a single one that looks like this:

```js
ec_Event : [
  {
    pid: '9783834649867', sku: '9783834649867', name: 'Book 1'
  }, {
    pid: '9683271123215', sku: '7552163721', name: 'Book 2'
  }
 ]
```

I tried `let merge = {...data}`, but it doesn't seem to merge them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you iterate over objects, create an array and with each iteration add the object to that array with [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
const arr = [];
Object.entries(buyProductData).forEach(entry => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    if(typeof value === 'object') {
        const {sku,...restProperties} = JSON.parse(value.getAttribute('data-tracking-payload'));
        // console.log(data);
        arr.push({DUS:sku,...restProperties});
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution worked as well.

Comment: One more question. How can I change the propery name: like in my example both objects have and 'sku' name. Is there any way to change that to say 'DUS'? –

Comment: Yes, you could change a property extracted from an object with `destructuring` and `rest operator`, I've updated the answer!

Comment: Can this be used for filtering as well? Like I want to delete/filter out the name property

Comment: Yes, maybe this gonna be another question, But I hope my answer solves your problem

Comment: Yes, I’ve marked it as solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.map()` to transform you values into an array and `Array::filter()` to filter out values before the mapping.
Also you don't need `Object.entries()` because you don't use the keys, use `Object.values` instead.

```
Object.values(buyProductData)
    .filter(value => typeof value === 'object')
    .map(value => {
        const obj = JSON.parse(value.getAttribute('data-tracking-payload'));
        obj.DUS = obj.sku;
        delete obj.sku;
        return obj;
    });
```

You could also `Array::reduce()`:

```
Object.values(buyProductData).reduce((arr, value) => {
    if(typeof value === 'object'){
        const obj = JSON.parse(value.getAttribute('data-tracking-payload'));
        obj.DUS = obj.sku;
        delete obj.sku;
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    return arr;
}, []);
```

Comment: One more question.
How can I change the propery name: like in my example both objects have and 'sku' name. Is there any way to change that to say 'DUS'?